# Meaning of $K'[\cdot]$ when $K$ is an symmetric Onsager (matrix) operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is from the section 5.2 of the small book "*Entropy Methods for Diffusive Partial Differential Equations*" written by Ansgar Jungel. To be specific, I do not know what does it mean when the author stated (in page 117) $$(\partial_t K)\,\xi = K'[\partial_t \nu]\,\xi.$$ Also, it is very confusing to me as well when he said (again in page 117) $$ Q= -K'[\cdot]\,\log\rho - K\,\nu^{-1}.$$ Clearly $K$ is a matrix (operator) of infinite dimension, so $K\,\nu^{-1}$ should be a matrix as well. But $\log\rho$ is an infinite dimensional vector, so how could the term $-K'[\cdot]\,\log\rho$ become a matrix then? Thanks for any help!